# How to read a Git log graph

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

In the Git community book, it says

> Another interesting thing you can do is visualize the commit graph with the '--graph' option, like so:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph
* 2d3acf9 : ignore errors from SIGCHLD on trap
*   5e3ee11 : Merge branch 'master' of git://github.com/dustin/grit
|\
| * 420eac9 : Added a method for getting the current branch.
* | 30e367c : timeout code and tests
* | 5a09431 : add timeout protection to grit
* | e1193f8 : support for heads with slashes in them
|/
* d6016bc : require time for xmlschema
```

> It will give a pretty nice ASCII representation of the commit history lines.

How should I read this graph? How does `420eac9` differ from the rest?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The asterisks show where something was committed:

`e1193f8`, `5a09431` and `30e367c` were committed to the left branch (yielding a `|` on the right branch) whereas `420eac9` was committed to the right branch (yielding a `|` on the left branch). And **that** is how `420eac9` differs from the rest: it's the only commit to the right branch.

For the sake of completeness:

- `d6016bc` was the branching point
- `5e3ee11` is the merging commit
- `2d3acf9` is the first commit after merging

Comment: I had a question about commit times as shown in the graph. In the graph, '420eac9' is shown above '30e367c', '5a09431', and 'e1193f8'. Would that always mean that '420eac9' was committed after the other three, or is it that commits on a branch are grouped together, and the order in which they appear across branches, does not have a time correlation ?

Comment: @Parag: commits in a branch are grouped together. `420eac9`was done after the first commit of the `e1193f8` branch but not neccessarily after `30e367c`

Comment: @eckes so are the `|` symbols on the left (the most left) a representation of the branch that I'm currently on?

Comment: @J86 if you switch to another branch and run the same command,  you get the same output, so there's no reference in the graph to the current branch you are on

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @young_souvlaki here, at StackOverflow?

Comment: @eckes link the source.

Answer (score 22):

`420eac9` is on a different branch than the 3 commits "below" it. The branches diverged after `d6016bc` and they were merged in `5e3ee11`.

Comment: Maybe a better wording than the branches diverging is that a second branch was created from `d6016bc` and developed in parallel with the original branch.