# What is this git log --graph indicating?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

I have the following branches:

- master
- upgadingToJquery1.4
- handlingExceptions

I was working on the **upgradingToJquery1.4** branch and had made a few commits.

I created another branch **handlingExceptions** made some changes and committed them.

Then I switched back to master and merged the **handlingExceptions** branch. Surprisingly I think the changes in **upgradeToJquery1.4** branch also got merged. Then to confirm I merged the **upgradeToJquery1.4** branch and it said up to date.

Can someone just explain what the graph is indicating here?

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
    *   a54bd6d (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'upgradeToJquery1.4'
    |\
    | * d4f762c (upgradeToJquery1.4) main.sass updated
    * |   bcf7a4f Merge branch 'handlingExceptions'
    |\ \
    | * | 471c1ad (handlingExceptions) the postLogin method in the accountController catches the exceptions and now prov
    | |/
    | * 76145d1 1. css/images - Jquerymobile icon files
    | * 34bc7b9 custom-jqueryMobile.js - to override jquerymobile defaults. Currently added transitions doesn't work with p
```

Comment: This post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200226/how-to-understand-git-log-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally, you have this (all I have done here is redraw the graph horizontally):

```
          D    <-- upgradeToJquery1.4
        /   \
- A - B - C   \    <-- handlingExceptions
            \   \
------------- E - F  <-- HEAD=master
```

where:

```
A = 34bc7b9 custom-jqueryMobile.js - to ...
B = 76145d1 1. css/images - Jquerymobile icon files
C = 471c1ad the postLogin method in ...
D = d4f762c main.sass updated
E = bcf7a4f Merge branch 'handlingExceptions'
F = a54bd6d Merge branch 'upgradeToJquery1.4'
```

There are different ways to get here, but given that you created `handlingExceptions` (presumably with `git checkout -b`) the most straightforward would probably be this:

```
git checkout upgradeToJquery1.4
... make commit A (or maybe it was already there but you said make "a few" commits)
... make commit B
git checkout -b handlingExceptions
... make commit C
git checkout upgradeToJquery1.4
... make commit D
git checkout master
git merge handlingExceptions
git merge upgradeToJquery1.4
```

Another, different way to get here would be:

```
git checkout upgradeToJquery1.4
... make commits A, B, and D
git checkout HEAD^   # get back onto commit B
git checkout -b handlingExceptions
... make commit C
... now checkout master and merge as before
```

Or instead of a separate `git checkout HEAD^`, you could `git checkout -b handlingExceptions HEAD^` to create `handlingExceptions` such that commit `C` got `B` as its parent.

In any case, though, at the point at which `git merge handlingExceptions` occurred, you were on `master` and `handlingExceptions` pointed to commit `C`, so that created commit `E`.  The commit message and graph nodes support each other in this: `E`'s parents are something-not-shown (first parent) and `C` (2nd parent).  Then, while still on `master`, a *separate* `git merge upgradeToJquery1.4` created commit `F`, whose parents are `E` (first-parent) and `D` (2nd parent).

In any case, the branch labels point to commits `D`, `C`, and `F` now.